# How outside networks are able to connect to my computer that is behind Double NAT setup?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat

Let's say I made a request to webserver on port 80 and my source port is 53456. Normally on single NAT setup, the port gets mapped in external and internal routing table and the webserver will reach its destination just fine.

In case of Double NAT, would not the webserver not know that my computer source port was actually mapped on the 2# router at the time of sending the request?

How does the 1# router knows where to send my source port if it was mapped/changed at the time of sending a source port from 2# router?

Comment: Draw the scheme. Then trace a packet "by hands": on PC NIC, on router-1 LAN, on router-1 NAT, on router-1 WAN, on router2-LAN, ... and so on until web-server NIC. And back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double NAT works the same way as single NAT, it's just done twice. NAT gateways are transparent to clients and servers and other NAT gateways. Clients and servers don't do anything differently just because the traffic happens to be going through a NAT. NAT gateways don't do anything special just because the traffic might be going through a second NAT. In fact, they don't really have a good way to detect that a NAT is in use (other than assuming that RFC1918 private addresses imply NAT, which can be a bad assumption).